# JSON formatting in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, rest, api

Lets say I have three models and tables i.e. Schools, Class and students.
The School and Class are in one to many relation and Class and students are also in one to many relationship. Now I am creating a RESTFUL API to send all these data at once in this JSON format:

```
[{
        "1": {
            "school_id": 1,
            "school_name": "Havard",
            "Class": {
                "1": {
                    "class_id": 1,
                    "school_id": 1,
                    "class": "6",
                    "Student": {
                        "1": {
                            "Student_fname": "SomeName",
                            "Student_lname": "Last Name"
                        },
                        "2": {
                            "Student_fname": "Another",
                            "Student_lname": "AnotherLast"
                        }
                    },
                    "2": {
                        "class_id": 2,
                        "school_id": 28,
                        "class": "7",
                        "Student": {
                            "1": {
                                "Student_fname": "Anotherone",
                                "Student_lname": "Last"
                            },
                            "2": {
                                "Student_fname": "New",
                                "Student_lname": "Newer"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    },
    {
        "2": {
            "school_id": 1,
            "school_name": "AnotherSchool",
            "Class": {
                "1": {
                    "class_id": 1,
                    "school_id": 1,
                    "class": "6",
                    "Student": {
                        "1": {
                            "Student_fname": "SomeName",
                            "Student_lname": "Last Name"
                        },
                        "2": {
                            "Student_fname": "Another",
                            "Student_lname": "AnotherLast"
                        }
                    },
                    "2": {
                        "class_id": 2,
                        "school_id": 28,
                        "class": "7",
                        "Student": {
                            "1": {
                                "Student_fname": "Anotherone",
                                "Student_lname": "Last"
                            },
                            "2": {
                                "Student_fname": "New",
                                "Student_lname": "Newer"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

How do I achieve this format?  Is my this json format correct? Is there a better way to achieve it?

Comment: i think class(if classes are more than one) and student should be array of object(json).

Comment: Yes classes are more than one in a school. Could you show an example of a code to make it clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into Laravel API Resources.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like https://github.com/thephpleague/fractal, https://github.com/dingo/api or do it by making transformer methods in your controllers(or classes if you prefer)

Some pseudo code

```
<?php
class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function index(Request $request) {
        $users = Users::all(); 

        $response = []; 

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $response[] = $this->transform($user); 
        }

    }

    public function transform(User $user) {
        return [
            'username' => $user->username,
            'age' => $user->age,
            'class' => [
                'name' => $user->school->name,
                'something' => $user->school->something
            ]
        ];
    }

}
```

I higly recommend doing the transform-part in other classes than in the controller itself.

Answer (score 1):

For people visiting this question for a solution about JSON Formatting in Laravel, I recommend you use **JSON formatter** Extension on Chrome to test your API Responses instead of losing time for a simple task.
It's just my personal recommendation, you can create or use a plugin to manage JSON responses on your code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If like me, you want to format `JSON` `string` using `Laravel` `collection` please use the technique below:

```
$json = collect([
    'name' => 'Test',
    'description' => 'Another awesome laravel package',
    'license' => 'MIT'
  ﻿])->toJson(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);﻿

echo $json;
```

The output generated would have the below format:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "Another awesome laravel package",
    "license": "MIT"
}
```

The same technique can be applied to results of `eloquent` query. And writing `JSON` to files to `storage`.

Reference [link](https://dev.to/vittorioe/quick-tip-creating-pretty-json-files-with-laravel-nel)

Answer (score -1):

I think should be like this

```
[
"1": {
"school_id": 1,
    "school_name": "Havard",
    "Class": [
    "1": {
            "class_id": 1,
            "school_id": 1,
            "class": "6",
            "Student": [
                "1": {
                "Student_fname": "SomeName",
                    "Student_lname": "Last Name"
                }
            ]
         }
    ]
}
]
```